# Why is this LEFT JOIN running slowly?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, left-join

The `LEFT JOIN` portion of a PostgreSQL query is running quite slowly, and I can't figure out why.

**The full query:**

```
SELECT t.id FROM tests t
LEFT JOIN tests c ON c.parent_id IN (t.id, t.parent_id)
INNER JOIN responses r ON (
    r.test_id IN (t.id, t.parent_id, c.id)
) WHERE r.user_id = 333
```

There are indexes on `tests.id` and `tests.parent_id`.

Tests contains 28876 rows (of those, there are 1282 `WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL`).

The `LEFT JOIN` portion of the query is producing 32098 rows, and **takes about 700ms**.

```
SELECT t.id FROM tests t
LEFT JOIN tests c ON c.parent_id IN (t.id, t.parent_id)
```

The rest of the query is taking a negligible amount of time.

Any ideas as to why it might be slow, or a better way to achieve the same thing?

Thank you!

---

**SELECT VERSION()**

```
PostgreSQL 9.1.9 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit
```

**EXPLAIN ANALYZE**

(Note: this uses the real table name, `usability_tests`, which I had simplified as `tests` in earlier examples.)

```
Nested Loop  (cost=5.18..158692.45 rows=80 width=4) (actual time=107.873..5718.295 rows=103 loops=1)
  Join Filter: ((r.usability_test_id = t.id) OR (r.usability_test_id = t.parent_id) OR (r.usability_test_id = c.id))
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.56..136015.63 rows=28876 width=12) (actual time=0.091..486.496 rows=32098 loops=1)
        Join Filter: ((c.parent_id = t.id) OR (c.parent_id = t.parent_id))
        ->  Seq Scan on usability_tests t  (cost=0.00..1455.76 rows=28876 width=8) (actual time=0.042..39.558 rows=28876 loops=1)
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on usability_tests c  (cost=0.56..4.60 rows=4 width=8) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=0 loops=28876)
              Recheck Cond: ((parent_id = t.id) OR (parent_id = t.parent_id))
              ->  BitmapOr  (cost=0.56..0.56 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=28876)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_usability_tests_on_parent_id  (cost=0.00..0.28 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=28876)
                          Index Cond: (parent_id = t.id)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_usability_tests_on_parent_id  (cost=0.00..0.28 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=28876)
                          Index Cond: (parent_id = t.parent_id)
  ->  Materialize  (cost=4.62..153.63 rows=39 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.076 rows=70 loops=32098)
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on responses r  (cost=4.62..153.44 rows=39 width=4) (actual time=0.053..0.187 rows=70 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: (user_id = 3649)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_responses_on_user_id  (cost=0.00..4.61 rows=39 width=0) (actual time=0.040..0.040 rows=70 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = 3649)
Total runtime: 5718.592 ms
```

Comment: Are you trying to recursively query the hierarchy in that table? If yes, then you need a CTE for that.

Comment: I would consider trying a Union with the conditions split into two queries. Can I ask what the purpose is of checking if the parent ids match, is this just to make sure you get every record in tests at least once?

Comment: @ChrisProsser This is only a portion of a larger query which does further filtering based on the attributes of the joined table `c`. In isolation I can see that the `DISTINCT` results of this query are no different from `SELECT id from tests`.

Comment: Just as a side note indexes generally help with speed a lot when you are filtering to select a small proportion of the table, but do not speed things up when you have to return a large proportion of the table.

Comment: **Always** show your exact PostgreSQL version (`SELECT version()`) and `explain analyze` results if asking about query performance. *Always*.

Comment: BTW: the `... JOIN ON a IN (b , c) ...` idiom is awkward. I have problems understanding it, especially in combination with the LEFT join. Am I the only one in this? Maybe you should add the _intention_ of this query (as text) too?

Comment: Added version and `explain analyze`, @CraigRinger. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Table definitions would help, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update**: Looks like your query is basically something like this

```
with cte as (
    select r.test_id
    from responses as r
    where r.user_id = 333
    union all
    select c.parent_id
    from tests as c
        inner join responses as r on r.test_id = c.id
    where r.user_id = 333
)
select
    t.id
from tests as t
where
    t.id in (select c.test_id from cte as c) or
    t.parent_id in (select c.test_id from cte as c)
```

**old**: try to turn this into this query and see if it would be faster:

```
select t.id 
from tests t
    inner join tests c on c.parent_id = t.id

union all

select t.id 
from tests t
    inner join tests c oN c.parent_id = t.parent_id
```

How long it takes to do one of these queries?

Comment: This is significantly faster (160ms), but doesn't lend itself to the filtering I want to do on the results. See updated OP. Thanks.

Comment: I've got to learn about `CTE` (a new concept to me) to fully understand what's going on here, but your query produces the desired result, **and in under 40ms**. Thanks, and kudos!

Answer (score 1):

I *think* the query can be reduced to:

```
SELECT t.id FROM tests t
WHERE EXISTS ( 
        SELECT * FROM responses r
        WHERE (r.test_id = t.id OR r.test_id = t.parent_id )
        AND r.user_id = 333
        )
OR EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM responses r 
        JOIN tests c ON r.test_id = c.id
            -- Note: the ... OR sibling makes no sense to me
        WHERE (c.parent_id = t.id OR c.parent_id = t.parent_id)
        AND r.user_id = 333
        );
```

Note: the query in the question *could* produce duplicate values for `t.id`. This one only reports distinct values.

UPDATE: I just tested it (on synthetic data), and the above query returns exactly the same results as the original *minus the duplicates*.

UPDATE2: added the sibling match.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't quite produce the desired result. It produces the same as my query if the LEFT JOIN where changed to `c.parent_id = t.id`. (ie. It misses joins where `c.parent_id = t.parent_id`)

Comment: IMO the "missing" rows will all be duplicate ids, since the t query already has yielded the particular id. (try adding a distinct to your original query, to get the same count)

Comment: The missing rows aren't duplicates. I have submitted an edit of your answer that catches the additional case where `c.parent_id = t.parent_id`, and this version of your query produces the correct result in ~350ms. A marked improvement! Thanks sincerely for your input. The big green tick went to @RomanPekar this time for the fastest query.